# Cloudify and High Availability

Tags: cloudify

I'm using Cloudify 2.7 with OpenStack Icehouse, for a production environment.

I would like to have High Availability of Cloudify Manager, so that the state of the deployed applications can be saved and restored in case of problems.

Which of the following solutions is the correct?

1) Create 2 Cloudify Managers, in each of them set a persistencePath property in the cloud configuration file;

2) Create 2 Cloudify Managers, without setting a persistencePath property in the cloud configuration file;

3) Create 1 Cloudify Manager, with a  persistencePath property in the cloud configuration file

Could I execute, by means of a bash script into the Cloudify Manager, the Cloudify command that saves the state of the deployed applications (I mean, the command that corresponds to the shutdown-managers) using a cron task ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1 is a bad one and not supported (note that Cloudify 2.7 is not supported AT ALL - it has reached end of life).

Both 2 and 3 are good options. 2 gives you High-Availability, 3 gives you manager recovery.

There is no command that saves the state of the manager - state is saved every time there is a change (and persisted to the persistencePath directory)

Comment: You have asked a lot of cloudify questions, but have not closed them, either accepting answers or stating the problem with the answers.